# Syntax errors when using tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have imported tkinter at the beginning of my code and below is what I have at the end for the GUI.  All worked fine with the GUI running and buttons displaying until I wrote the code for 'strengthSkill' and now I am getting a sytax error at the beginning of this line:

```
mlabel=Label(text='Battle!!').place(x=50,y=130)
```

It is highlighting "mlabel" as the error but I have looked and can't see what the problem is.  I have created a second version where everything Tkinter is stripped out and all works fine.

```
mGui = Tk()
   ment = diceint()


   mGui.geometry('400x400')
   mGui.configure(bg="purple")
   mGui.title('Miss Watts Dice Games')


   mlabel=Label(text='4,6,12 sided dice roller').place(x=50,y=50)
   mbutton=Button(mGui,text="Go",command=diceroll).place(x=250,y=50)
   mentry=Entry(mGui,variable=ment).pack()

   mlabel=Label(text='Strength and skill calculator').place(x=50,y=90)
   mbutton=Button(mGui,text="Go",command=strengthSkill.place(x=250,y=90)

   mlabel=Label(text='Battle!!').place(x=50,y=130)
   mbutton=Button(mGui,text="Go",command=battle.place(x=250,y=130)


   mbutton=Button(mGui,text="Exit",command=close).place (x=50,y=250)

   mlabel=Label(text='\N{COPYRIGHT SIGN} Dru Watts 2014').place(x=50,y=300)

   mGui.mainloop()
```

Unfortunately I can't post the main part of the code as I am creating an example to show my students of the controlled assessment coursework they need to complete and I'd rather they didn't find this!

Please be gentle - VERY new to tkinter.  Worried I may have mixed up tutorials a bit too much!

Comment: I'd **strongly** recommend using an editor that automatically pairs parens, brackets, etc., and highlights when one is missing. You'll avoid a lot of errors like this that way.

Comment: @MattDMo I agree, I've been thinking about getting a different editor as I'm using OSX and for some reason the python editor doesn't show my cursor  - infuriating!  Could you recommend something for OSX?

Comment: Many programmers really like [Sublime Text](http://sublimetext.com/3). Even though it's technically in "beta", I'd recommend getting version 3 over version 2, as the API has been improved in many places and lots of [plugins](https://sublime.wbond.net) have taken advantage of it. There are several `[sublimetext]`-related tags on SO if you have questions.

Comment: unrelated to the question asked, but here's some helpful advice: use `grid` or `pack` rather than `place`, and put widget creation and widget layout in two separate statements (ie: don't do `Label(...).place(...)`). Stackoverflow is littered with questions stemming from those basic anti-patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis here:

```
mbutton=Button(mGui,text="Go",command=strengthSkill).place(x=250,y=90)
                                                   ^
```

and here:

```
mbutton=Button(mGui,text="Go",command=battle).place(x=250,y=130)
                                            ^
```

---

Also, because the `place` and `pack` methods of every Tkinter widget work in-place,`mbutton`, `mlabel`, etc. will all be assigned to `None`. Thus, if you plan to use these variables later on, you will need to call these methods on their own lines:

```
mlabel=Label(text='4,6,12 sided dice roller')
mlabel.place(x=50,y=50)
```

Otherwise, I would recommend removing the variables altogether because they are unnecessary:

```
Label(text='4,6,12 sided dice roller').place(x=50,y=50)
Button(mGui,text="Go",command=diceroll).place(x=250,y=50)
Entry(mGui,variable=ment).pack()
```

Comment: Awesome, that's solved that one.  Can't believe I missed it! It worked before so I must have deleted it by accident.  Thank you.

Comment: I'll also have a look at place and removing the variables.  Not finished yet so not sure if I'll need them. Thanks :)